# Replacing chemform in wiki - regexp

Tags: regex

could you please give me some advice, I'm replacing the `<chemform>` code from my wiki which is not used any more... The strings are usually simple like these:

```
<chemform>CH3COO-</chemform>
<chemform>Ba2+</chemform>
<chemform>H2CO3</chemform>
```

I need them to be replaced by these:

```
CH<sub>3</sub>COO<sup>-</sup>
Ba<sub>2</sub><sup>+</sup>
H<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub>
```

So far I came up with this regexp for the [RegExr tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/):

*match*: `<chemform\b[^>]*>(\D*?)([0-9]*)(\D*?)(\D*?)([0-9]*)(\D*?)([-+]*?)</chemform>`

*replace*: `$1<sub>$2</sub>$3$4<sub>$5</sub>$6<sup>$7</sup>`

I know the code is horrible, but so far it's been working for me except for the fact it's getting me empty strings like `<sub></sub>`:

```
<sub></sub>CH<sub>3</sub>COO<sup>-</sup>
<sub></sub>Ba<sub>2</sub><sup>+</sup>
H<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub><sup></sup>
```

How can I get rid of these without doing second replace search? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Won't work for eg `<chemform>NH4C2H3O2</chemform>`. Pretty much for the same reason. You could use regex to match `<chemform>` tags, then use a separate function to parse and create the replacement.

Comment: Do you have the input that resulted in the empty strings shown above?

Comment: It's the 

`<chemform>CH3COO-</chemform>
<chemform>Ba2+</chemform>
<chemform>H2CO3</chemform>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use Notepad++, which is able to proceed to conditional replacements (you can have details in that [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37161309/8767753) from [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)).

Use the following patterns:

- match: `([A-Za-z]+(?=[-+\d]))(?<sub>\d+)?(?<sup>[-+])?(?=[-+\w]*</chemform>)`
- replace: `$1(?{sub}<sub>$+{sub}</sub>)(?{sup}<sup>$+{sup}</sup>)`

Given your input sample, I get:

```
<chemform>CH<sub>3</sub>COO<sup>-</sup></chemform>  
<chemform>Ba<sub>2</sub><sup>+</sup></chemform>  
<chemform>H<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub></chemform>
```