# How to use conditionals when replacing in Notepad++ via regex

Tags: regex, notepad++, conditional-statements

Consider the following regex:

`([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]?)/([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]?)`

If the text is: `a/b`
the capturing groups will be:

```
/1  'a'
/2  ''
/3  'b'
/4  ''
```

And if the text is: `aa/b`
the capturing groups will be:

```
/1  'a'
/2  'a'
/3  'b'
/4  ''
```

Suppose, I want to find and replace this string in Notepad++ such that if `/2` or `/4` are empty (as in the first case above), I prepend `c`.

So, the text `a/b` becomes `ca/cb`.
And the text `aa/b` becomes `aa/cb`

I use the following regex for replacing:

```
(?(2)\1\2|0\1)/(?(4)\3\4|0\3)
```

But Notepad++ is treating `?` literally in this case, and not as a conditional identifier. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think your placement of the `?` may be incorrect and this could be why Notepad++ is treating them as literals.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The syntax in the conditional replacement is

```
(?{GROUP_MATCHED?}REPLACEMENT_IF_YES:REPLACEMENT_IF_NO)
```

The `{` and `}` are necessary to avoid ambiguity when you deal with groups higher than 9 and with named capture groups.

Since Notepad++ uses *`Boost-Extended Format String Syntax`*, see this [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html#boost_regex.format.boost_format_syntax.conditionals):

> The character `?` begins a conditional expression, the general form is:

`?Ntrue-expression:false-expression`

> where `N` is decimal digit.

> If sub-expression `N` was matched, then `true-expression` is evaluated and sent to output, otherwise `false-expression` is evaluated and sent to output.

> You will normally need to surround a conditional-expression with parenthesis in order to prevent ambiguities.

> For example, the format string `(?1foo:bar)` will replace each match found with `foo` if the sub-expression `$1` was matched, and with `bar` otherwise.

> For sub-expressions with an index greater than 9, or for access to named sub-expressions use:

> `?{INDEX}true-expression:false-expression`

> or

> `?{NAME}true-expression:false-expression`

So, use `([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])?/([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])?` and replace with `(?{2}$1$2:c$1)/(?{4}$3$4:c$3)`.

The second problem is that you placed the `?` quantifier inside the capturing group, making the pattern inside the group optional, but *not the whole group*. That made the group always "participating in the match", and the condition would be always "true" (always matched). **`?` should quantify the group**.

[image]

Comment: Can you also link to the documentation (if any) specific to Notepad++ ?

Comment: I included the Boost reference.