# Conditional Regular Expression Replace Where String is NOT in the Initial Expression

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I will just give a few examples as I think that is the best way to describe what I want, but basically I want to only keep the number but prepend text to the start depending on the first number (1 or 2: AAA, 3: BBB, 4 or 5: XYZ):

INITIAL STRINGS:

```
Blah 12345 Blah
Blah 22345 Blah
Blah 32345 Blah
Blah 42345 Blah
Blah 52345 Blah
```

RESULT:

```
AAA12345
AAA22345
BBB32345
XYZ42345
XYZ52345
```

Regex to search for:

```
([0=9])([0-9]{4})
```

Regex To replace with:

```
(SOME WAY OF DECIDING BETWEEN AAA|BBB|XYZ depending on \1!)\1\2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I've had a look around but everything I found always replaced the text with something in the search string, and wondered if this was possible. Thanks in advance folks. :)

Comment: Bit of advice folks - all great solutions (upvoted all). Like Nadia's as it was the right answer and she was first; Wiktor's as it was right and went into more detail; and Casimir's as it was right and works without the need for Notepad++ (which I really like). Normally when everyone is right I give the "answer" to the person was the lowest cred as it's tough starting out. Does that sound fair? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I agree. Also, since revo removed his answer, I upvoted two of his other answers, so we are all happy I hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to indeed be a way to do that with Notepad++ as it supports conditional replacement, which is detailed in the accepted answer of this question: [How to use conditionals when replacing in Notepad++ via regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160927/how-to-use-conditionals-when-replacing-in-notepad-via-regex/37161309)

But please note that it might be easier and quicker to just do multiple Find/Replace for each of your cases...

Comment: Thanks Nadia - wrote my own on the back of this and it works! :)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use the regex conditional feature here (i.e.: `(?(condition)true|false)`.

You can do it creating a fake last line (without newline at the end) with the data you need:

```
Blah 12345 Blah
Blah 22345 Blah
Blah 32345 Blah
Blah 42345 Blah
Blah 52345 Blah
AAA#BBB#XYZ
```

and use this pattern:

```
^[^0-9\n]*(?:((?|[12](?=(?>.*\n)*([^#]+))|3(?=(?>.*\n)*[^#]*#([^#]+))|[45](?=(?>.*\n)*(?:[^#]*#){2}([^#]+)))\d+).*|.*\z)
```

and this replacement:

```
$2$1
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/dS6jV9/1)

pattern details:

```
^ # start of a line
[^0-9\n]* # all that isn't a digit
(?:
    ( # first capture group for the number
        (?| # branch reset: all capture have the same number inside (2 here)
            [12]
            (?= # lookahead to reach the good string
                (?>.*\n)* # reach the last line
                ([^#]+)   # capture the first string
            )
          |
            3
            (?=
                (?>.*\n)*
                [^#]*#    # skip the first string
                ([^#]+)   # capture the second
            )
          | # same thing
            [45](?=(?>.*\n)*(?:[^#]*#){2}([^#]+))
        ) # close the branch reset group
        \d+
     ) # close the capture group 1
     .* # match the end of the line
  |
    .*\z # match the last line
)
```

Comment: I deleted my answer since it wasn't the only answer with unique solution and going to upvote yours since it's *different* and has an *idea*.

Comment: Wow, Casimir, this completely messed with my head - will look more closely at this when I have more time, but very interesting thank you! :)

Comment: @revo: thanks, I think your solution was the good one, I didn't know it was possible to use a conditional replacement in notepad++.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
^.* ((?:([12])|(3)|([45]))\d{4}) .*
```

and replace with

```
(?2AAA:(?3BBB:XYZ))$1
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of line
- `.*` - zero or more chars other than a newline up to the last
- `((?:([12])|(3)|([45]))\d{4})`  - a space, 1 specific digit (`1` or `2` - Group 2, `3` - Group 3, `4` - Group 4, and 4 more digits
- `.*` - the rest of the line

*Replacement pattern details*:

- `(?2` - If the second group matched,

  - `AAA` - add `AAA`
  - `:` - or
  - `(?3` - if Group 3 matches,

    - `BBB` - inset `BBB`
    - `:` - or
    - `XYZ` - insert `XYZ`
  - `)`
- `)`
- `$1` - and insert Group 1 contents (the whole 5 digit number).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, exactly what I was after. :)

Comment: Glad you used my other answer to build your own pattern :)