# Can I find and replace multiple words at the same time in sublime text 3?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I want to find and replace several words at the same time in sublime, for example I want to replace word1,word2,word3 by word4,word5,word6 at the same time instead of doing them in 3 steps. Can I do it in sublime? if not how can I come up with a regexp to do this? 
Thank you

Comment: Just to clear it out: Sublime Text replacement patterns only allow [Perl Format String Syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/perl_format.html). Notepad++ replacement patterns support [Boost-Extended Format String Syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html) and can do what you need with the simple regex S&R. See [How to use conditionals when replacing in Notepad++ via regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160927/37161309#37161309).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case ***sed*** command might help you.

```
sed -i -e 's/word1/replace1/g' fileName && sed -i -e 's/word2/replace2/g' fileName && ...
```

and this goes on how many of words you need to replace, you can. Just run this on your **terminal**

Example:

> this is a content of file. File name is t.txt

I want to replace ***this*** with ***that*** and ***file*** with ***FILE***. then command will be :

```
sed -i -e 's/this/that/g' t.txt && sed -i -e 's/file/FILE/g' t.txt
```

output will be :

> **that** is a content of **FILE**. File name is t.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern `word1(.*)word2(.*)word3` to match the words, if the words to be replaced come in sequential order with or without some characters in between and use `word4\1word5\2word6\3` as replacement.

The pattern has used 3 capture groups to match characters if any between the words to be replaced. `\1`,`\2` and `\3` represent each captured group.

Here, the replacement pattern says that the matched text has to be replaced with the sequence of **word4 followed by the characters captured in first capture group i.e. the characters if any between the word 1 and word2, followed by word5 and so on**.

Comment: thank you, but I want to replace several word1 and several word2 and several word3 they can't be combined to match a certain pattern as you specified