# Regex to change numbers to the next one in line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm stuck trying to figure how to implement an idea to my files, my idea is to change numbers to the next one in order, so:

- 0 to 1
- 1 to 2
- 3 to 4 and so on.

This can easily be done with find and replace boxes, but the problem is if I start finding and replacing, the numbers I just increased will change again, I know this kinda doesn't make sense but I need a regex that changes all numbers in the file once to the next number in line

So let's say a line has a 0 and I change it to a 1, I need it to stay a to a 1 and not a 2 when I find and replace 1 to 2, I don't know if I'm explaining myself please anyone help

Examples

```
Order66
fight01
fly45
```

I need to be

```
Order77
Flight12
fly56
```

If I keep changing them manually with find and replace, they will turn out way different since I keep finding and replacing, that's why I need one regex to do it all at once

Comment: You have sample input/output?

Comment: added some samples, idk if  yall see what i mean

Comment: That's exactly what I meant thanks!

Comment: What happens when you reach 9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Brief

In Notepad++ you can use conditional replacements with regex. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160927/how-to-use-conditionals-when-replacing-in-notepad-via-regex) by Wiktor for more information.

---

### Code

```
(0)|(1)|(2)|(3)|(4)|(5)|(6)|(7)|(8)|(9)
```

Replacement

```
(?{1}1)(?{2}2)(?{3}3)(?{4}4)(?{5}5)(?{6}6)(?{7}7)(?{8}8)(?{9}9)(?{10}0)
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
Order66
fight01
fly45
```

[image: Code before regex replace]

#### Output

Below output after clicking on `Replace All` in Notepad++

```
Order77
Flight12
fly56
```

[image: Code after regex replace]

---

### Explanation

- Each digit is enclosed in its own group i.e. `(0)`.

  - Each group is given a different identifier. i.e. `(0)` is group 1
- In the replacement we can conditionally target groups that contain values and, as such `(?{1}1)` targets the first capture group and replaces its contents with `1` (`(?{1})` references capture group 1)