# Parenthesis around alpha characters, brackets around numbers, in one go

Tags: regex

I'm trying to put parenthesis around every character and brackets around every line using Regex in Sublime Text (actually, I don't mind which flavor, because I can always use [regex101](https://regex101.com/)).

I want to do this in one go. I can do this in two steps, but is it possible in one?

My input:

```
awKJ38W3i
```

My goal output:

```
(a)(w)(K)(J){3}{8}(W){3}(i)
```

**What I've done so far:**

I've been able to create two groups, 1 and 2, which match characters and numbers:

```
([A-z])|([0-9])

([A-z]) : Matches individual alpha characters and set as group 1
|       : OR
([0-9]) : Matches individual numeric characters and set as group 2
```

Now the problem is during the replacing. I want to replace the `[A-z]` with `\($1\)` and the `[0-9]` with `\{$1\}` but simultaneously. How can I do this?

I tried replacing it with

```
\($1\)|\{$2\}
```

but that doesn't seem to be the correct syntax.

Comment: Can you do it in 2 passes?

Comment: No. I don't think Sublime allows evaluating conditional expressions in replacement strings

Comment: You can do it in 1 pass using Notepad++.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I want to do this on multiple occasions, so it seems that doing it in multiple passes is a bit onerous

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you kindly give me some direction as to how I could do this using Notepad++?

Comment: Use `([a-zA-Z])|\d` and replace with `(?1\($1\):{$0})`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what does this part do?: `(?1 )` is the colon part of it? `:` like `(?:)` ?

Comment: It is a conditional replacement pattern. If Group 1 matches then... else...

Comment: If notepad++ see the docs http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html

Comment: If you are fine with NPP, let's close with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160927/how-to-use-conditionals-when-replacing-in-notepad-via-regex).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew All right, thanks.