# RegExp - Notepad++ combine statements

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I'm missing something with this regular expression find/replace attempt. I have the following format:

```
word | word | word
```

I would like to first replace every `word` with `"word"` to produce

```
"word" | "word" | "word"
```

and then subsequently every `[space]|` with `,`, finally producing

```
"word", "word", "word"
```

Obviously I could just do this with two simple find(f)/replace(r) commands ( f:`([a-z]*\>)`r:`"$1"`; f:`[space]|`r:`,`), but is there a way to do all of this at once?

I've tried lots of different ideas, but they all failed. The most successful was finding `([a-z]*\>)(( \|)|\R)` and replacing with `"$1",`, which only ever got me a `"word", "word", word` format. The solution is probably either much more complicated or much simpler than I'm trying, but I'm stumped. Thanks!

Comment: I am also stumped.  I don't even think we could phrase this replacement in an app language using a single regex, because the replacements are multiple things.  Honestly, I like the first approach you described, and I don't see anything wrong with that.  +1 to an otherwise good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(\w+)|\s*\|
```

and replace with `(?1"$1":,)`.

**Details**

- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `|` - or
- `\s*\|` - 0+ whitespaces and then a `|` char.
- `(?1"$1":,)`  - a conditional replacement pattern that replaces with `"` + Group 1 contents + `"` if Group 1 matches, else, replaces with `,`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much - what kind of documentation are you consulting/did you once consult to learn this? The notepad++ documentation is confusingly worded, and I didn't see this cool conditional pattern explained very well, if it was explained at all. Also, very clear formatting and details, very much appreciated!

Comment: @MichaelFrake See [How to use conditionals when replacing in Notepad++ via regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37161309/3832970). Here is the relevant [Boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html).