# How to change all non-word characters to a dash and trim the string of dashes in one regex?

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

I would like to find a regex and replacement to do all the following tasks at once:

1. Replace all `'s` that are ending words to the same word but with `s` instead (regex: `'s\b`, replacement: `s`)
2. Remove all non-word characters at the start and at the end of the string (regex: `^\W*(.*?)\W*$`, replacement: `\1`)
3. Replace all consecutive other non-word characters with a single dash (regex: `\W+`, replacement: `-`)

As seen I'm able to write all the rules one by one, but all together is much, much harder. I can't reduce the number of regexes to use...

I'd say that if it works on [regex101](https://regex101.com/), that's good enough. If it's not possible, I can accept that and saying so is good enough.

Examples:

```
Input               --->   Output
-----                      ------ 
Hello, World!       --->   hello-world
(%O'Shea's,*cAt!§   --->   o-sheas-cat
```

Comment: You can do all in a single step using Notepad++.

Comment: Which language? Lowercase conversions are not typical in regex engines, so you're not going to be language-agnostic regardless of the method you choose. Also, what makes `O'Shea's` become `o-sheas` and not `o-shea-s`??

Comment: @ctwheels Thank you, I wasn't aware, so I'll say that if one rule is optional, it's that one.

Comment: You'll need two replacements: `'(?=s\b)` replace with nothing and then `\W+` replace with `-`. Then convert to lowercase.

Comment: @ctwheels regarding "O'Shea's", the rule number 1. See the regex and the replacement.

Comment: P.S. what @revo is referring to can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37161309)

Comment: Task number 3 replacement is with a dash. Tasks 1 and 2 are with nothing. The replacement has to do logic if these are to be combined. The simple logic of the boost special replacement mode used by Notepad++ can be used for a one-off thing. But, if a cross-platform, permanent solution is required, the particular regex engine and host become important. Sorry, but thats the way it is.

Comment: By the way, your second rule is satisfied by your third - you can remove the second rule entirely.

Comment: @ctwheels No, [`\w` matches the underscore (`_`), not the dash (`-`)](https://regex101.com/r/Lou5U6/1).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire right, and you have `\W` in both rules; therefore, the third rule accomplishes everything the second one does. Think about it this way `\W*` will match whatever `\W+` does

Comment: @ctwheels `???abc???` will be `-abc-` with rule 3. With rule 2 it will become `abc`. Do I get anything wrong here?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire gotcha, you mean the replacement. OK so you can combine your first and second rule: `'(?=s\b)|^\W+|\W+$`

Comment: 1 and 2 combined and replace with nothing. So my previous `Task number 3 replacement is with a dash. Tasks 1 and 2 are with nothing.`, et all.. will apply

Comment: Okay, that seems good enough. Thank you both for your help. It can't be reduced to one expression with something else than boost, and the lowercasing isn't available everywhere. Now I know. Great!

Comment: Indeed with NP++ you could use a conditional replacement, eg search for `(\w+)|'(?=\w\b)|^\W+|\W+$|(\W+)` and replace with `(?1\L\1:(?2-:))`