# How to use regex to replace string with fixed size of char

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

Let's say I have the following text :

```
TimeOut_BN:1292 ms
TimeOut_BN:130 ms
TimeOut_BN:1313 ms
TimeOut_BN:1329 ms
TimeOut_BN:19 ms
TimeOut_BN:5 ms
TimeOut_BN:154 ms
```

I want to replace all numbers with formatted numbers (exactly 4 chars)

```
TimeOut_BN:1292 ms
TimeOut_BN: 130 ms
TimeOut_BN:1313 ms
TimeOut_BN:1329 ms
TimeOut_BN:  19 ms
TimeOut_BN:   5 ms
TimeOut_BN: 154 ms
```

I use the following regex to find the numbers

```
BN:(.*)\sms
```

But I don't know how to tell "Replace with exactly 4 chars".

Is there a way to do this ?

---

@revo It looks great, the idea is good, but when I tested it on regex101 I got :

```
TimeOut_BN:(?{1} 1292)(?{2}  )(?{3}   ) ms
TimeOut_BN:(?{1} )(?{2}  130)(?{3}   ) ms
TimeOut_BN:(?{1} 1313)(?{2}  )(?{3}   ) ms
TimeOut_BN:(?{1} 1329)(?{2}  )(?{3}   ) ms
TimeOut_BN:(?{1} )(?{2}  )(?{3}   19) ms
TimeOut_BN:(?{1} )(?{2}  )(?{3}   ) ms
TimeOut_BN:(?{1} )(?{2}  154)(?{3}   ) ms
```

Comment: You need either  a callback function as a replacement, or a conditional replacement support (available in Boost, PCRE2)

Comment: Which programming language do you use (if any?).

Comment: @Jan I don't use programming language , only Notepad ++

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew If you have some example or link it will be find.

Comment: Try to find `^TimeOut_BN:\K(?:(\d{3})|(\d\d)|(\d))\b` and replace with `(?{1} $1)(?{2}  $2)(?{3}   $3)`

Comment: Notepad++ uses Boost, you are lucky. See [How to use conditionals when replacing in Notepad++ via regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160927/how-to-use-conditionals-when-replacing-in-notepad-via-regex)

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to do it in one step, first try to find:

```
^TimeOut_BN:\K(?:(\d{3})|(\d\d)|(\d))\b
```

then replace it with

```
(?{1} $1)(?{2}  $2)(?{3}   $3)
```

Comment: Because you can't test it there. It's specific to Boost engine which N++ utilizes.

Comment: Fine, I test it on notepad++ and it works . How do you know such tricks ?