# Move comma-separated numbers and individual numbers to the next line, skipping specific lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list like following:

```
Play3
123,777
One
23,000
etet55
Hero12
vrtg1,345
2
Jan2003
```

Now I want to move `comma-separated numbers and normal numbers` to next line while skip specific lines.
**lines that must skip:**

```
^(Play3|One|Hero12)$
\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b
```

**values that must move to next lines:**

```
(?<!\d)0*\K(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|(?!0+(?!\d))\d{1,4})(?!\d)  
\d+
```

this mean above sample list must convert to following list:

```
Play3

123,777
One

23,000
etet
55
Hero12
vrtg
1,345

2
Jan2003
```

note that comma-separated numbers and normal numbers must placed at the end of line or line must start and end with them. lines can't start with a number and end with a character like following:

```
12Word
```

I tried following regex but I failed:

```
find : ^(Play3|One|Hero12)$|\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b|(?<!\d)0*\K(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|(?!0+(?!\d))\d{1,4})(?!\d)|\d+
replace : $1\n$2\n$3\n$4

find : ^(Play3|One|Hero12)$|\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b|\d+|0*\K(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|\d{1,4})
replace : $1\n$2\n$&

find : ^(Play3|One|Hero12)$|\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b|\d+(?:,\d{3})*|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+
replace : $1\n$2\n$3
```

where is my problem?

note that `(?<!\d)0*\K(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|(?!0+(?!\d))\d{1,4})(?!\d)` regex can't select both of comma-separated and normal number values.

Comment: If your subpatterns are fine, just match and skip what you do not need, and match and replace what you need, `(?:^(?:Play3|One|Hero12)$|\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<!\d)0*\K(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|(?!0+(?!\d))\d{1,4})(?!\d)|\d+` and replace with `\n$0`. I checked and it seems to work, but it is too big and looks awkward.

Comment: Match `(?:^(?:Play3|One|Hero12)$|\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b)(*SKIP)(*F)|\d+(?:\,\d+)*` and replace with `\n$0`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this method is good but how to select only comma-separated numbers and normal numbers that placed in end of lines only or lines that start and end with them? for example In `3ghth45hyh45` must only `45` move to next line

Comment: You cannot edit with a regexp,  as regexps are matching objects... if you want to change, you have to look for tools that match (probably using a regexp) parts of the text and then change these parts by something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In notepad++ you can use 2 capture groups with a conditional replacement:

**Find what:**

```
^(?:Play3|One|Hero12|.*\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b.*)$(*SKIP)(*F)|\d+(?:,\d+)*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:Play3|One|Hero12|.*\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b.*)$` Match one of `Play3` `One` `Hero12` on a single line, or match a line that matches one of the Month names followed by 4 digits
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` Skip the match
- `|` Or
- `\d+(?:,\d+)*` Match 1+ digits with an optional repeated decimal part in group 2
- `$` End of string

**Replace with:**

```
\n$0
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U1azli/1)

---

[image]

If you want to use the logic for the digits as well:

```
^(?:Play3|One|Hero12|\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b)$(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<![\d,])(?![0,]*$)(?:0*\K(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|\d{1,4}))$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Phiket/1)

Comment: This conditional replacement is new for me

Comment: @anubhava Wiktor made a nice post about it years ago here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160927/how-to-use-conditionals-when-replacing-in-notepad-via-regex

Comment: why `etet55` have no any changes?

Comment: @PubgMobile It does, but if it is direct to a next line that should match, then `^(?:Play3|One|Hero12|.*\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\d{4}\b.*)$\R^.*?(*SKIP)(*F)|([^\s\d])?(\d+(?:,\d+)?)$` and replace with `(?{1}$1\n$2:\n$2)`

Comment: can you tell me why your regex move `715,455` from end of `1,715,455` to next line?

Comment: @PubgMobile Do you want to move it like this? https://regex101.com/r/d0Kfta/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird it is very good but now if line include only a zero number it can't move zero number to next line, I mean `^0$`

Comment: @PubgMobile Then you can use the first pattern https://regex101.com/r/U1azli/1 I thought you did not wanted to match lines with only zeroes?