# How to remove the leading space and replace white spaces by tab in one go in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Try to manipulate the text file containing

```
 -1.     1      1  4.34E+4
 -1.     2      1  4.73E+3
  4.     1      1  4.78E+3  2.8E+3
  4.     7      1  2.62E+3  1.4E+2
  4.     8      1  2.22E+6  7.6E+03
  ...
```

to be

```
-1. 1   1   4.34E+4
-1. 2   1   4.73E+3
4.  1   1   4.78E+3 2.8E+3
4.  7   1   2.62E+3 1.4E+2
4.  8   1   2.22E+6 7.6E+03
...
```

The following two-steps can reach the goal, but is it possible to combine them into one?

**Find What:**^ +
**Replace:**

followed by

**Find What:** +
**Replace:**\t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

**Find What**: `^(\h+)|\h+`
**Replace With**: `(?{1}:\t)` (or `(?1:\t)` since there is no digit that is a part of a replacement pattern after the `?1` here)

The `^(\h+)|\h+` pattern captures one or more horizontal whitespace at the start of any line into Group 1 and then matches any one or more horizontal whitespace chars anywhere on a line. Then, the replacement is a TAB char if Group 1 did not match, else, it is an empty string.

See the screenshot and demo:

[image]

Comment: Just read that "The { and } are necessary to avoid ambiguity when you deal with groups higher than 9 and with named capture groups." from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160927.

Comment: @MathArt Yes, so I prefer using them in all cases, it is not a big issue and makes it foolproof.